# how to get the parent,and its children ,children category details using php

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to display the a;; level categories.

```
function fn_blog_tree_format(Array $data, $parent = 0) { 
    $tree = array();
    foreach ($data as $d) {
        if ($d['parentid'] == $parent) {
            $children = fn_blog_tree_format($data, $d['id']);
            if (!empty($children)) {
                $d['_children'] = $children;

            }

            $tree[] = $d;
        }
    }


    return $tree;
}
```

I Used the above to code to display the all category level.Here I get the following output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [categoryname] => php
            [slugurl] => core-php
            [parentid] => 0
            [description] => Lorem Ipsum is  simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum  has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when  an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type  specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the  leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It  was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets  containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop  publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem  Ipsum.
            [_children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [categoryname] => yii
                            [slugurl] => yii
                            [parentid] => 1
                            [description] => Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It  has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it  over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at  Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure  Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through  the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the  undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33  of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by  Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of  ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem  Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section  1.10.32.
                            [_children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 4
                                            [categoryname] => demo
                                            [slugurl] => demo
                                            [parentid] => 2
                                            [description] => Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and  typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy  text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of  type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not  only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,  remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with  the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsu
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Now i want to change

```
 [_children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 4
                                            [categoryname] => demo
                                            [slugurl] => demo
                                            [parentid] => 2
                                            [description] => Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and  typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy  text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of  type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not  only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,  remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with  the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsu
                                        )

                                )
```

To

```
 [_subchildren] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 4
                                            [categoryname] => demo
                                            [slugurl] => demo
                                            [parentid] => 2
                                            [description] => Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and  typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy  text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of  type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not  only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,  remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with  the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsu
                                        )

                                )
```

How to i do . Please help me.

Comment: Is'n it a duplicate? There is [tons of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+tree) about recursive sorting of PHP arrays on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right, You want to rename all your children's children as `_subchildren`.
So, I am guessing that could be done by checking the value of the parent variable.
Try replacing the if condition block in the function with this -

```
if (!empty($children)) {
    if($parent == 0){
        $d['_children'] = $children;
    }else{
        $d['_subchildren'] = $children;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short idea I just had (but didn't test it): You could add an counter. Set this on 1 at the start and in the loop check if it's 1 before increment it. When it's 1 you do `$d['_children'] = $children;` otherwise (when it's higher than 1) you do `$d['_subchildren'] = $children;`

Redmint to reset the counter for every parent